# Couchdb package broken on 14.04 lts Trusty

Tags: 14.04, upstart, init, couchdb

Is there something wrong with couchdb packages in trusty/14.04?

When I install couchdb it doesn't start.  The install reports:

```
initctl: Unknown job: couchdb
```

and there is no `/etc/init.d/couchdb`

This occurs with both the standard package (1.5.0-0ubuntu1) and the couchdb PPA (1.6.1-0ubuntu5),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in upstart, not couchdb.  Running the install from within a desktop session causes upstart not to see the new job.  The service starts normally on reboot, or from a root shell unsullied with an UPSTART_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

From [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-and-futon-on-ubuntu-14-04), I am summarizing the main contents to just the commands you need to type for installing `couchdb`:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:couchdb/stable -y

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -yf

sudo apt-get install couchdb -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had a similar problem, searched for solutions and found this snippet:
https://github.com/pixelpark/ppnet/wiki/Install-CouchDB-1.6.1-on-Ubuntu-14.04

Turns out this method does generate `/etc/init.d/couchdb` so it may solve your problem. Here's the generated file:
https://gist.github.com/GabLeRoux/b50d7c88b8421eda0ae6

In my case, I installed couchdb `1.6.1` from `ppa:couchdb/stable` and service does work even without `/etc/init.d/couchdb`.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/init.d$ sudo service couchdb restart
couchdb stop/waiting
couchdb start/running, process 6898
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/init.d$ curl localhost:5984
{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"26b1f5a8b777f61674013da9a64c3728","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"14.04"}}
```